# Unbalanced tree conversion in db

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Assume that I insert of sequence of elements in any database-

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, 9,10

I'm sure this will create a unbalanaced index tree.

When does the unbalanced index tree will be converted into balanced tree by the database assume its Oracle.

Also, how can I implement  a logic in Java to convert a unbalanced tree to balanced tree.

Comment: For how to do this in Java, maybe check out AVL trees. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree

Answer (score 0):

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, 9,10 would create an unbalanced tree if you were using a standard binary tree. There are other binary trees, such as AVL trees which are self-balancing, and re-order the tree if an insert leads to an imbalance. According to [this](http://www.orafaq.com/node/1403) source Oracle use [B-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) for indexing.